# A puzzling newspaper headline

Tags: cryptic-clues

The following clues are not quite your usual crossword fare; they do fit the standard guidelines for cryptic clues, but each of them contains an unusual twist which (hopefully) makes them harder than average. By putting together all four solutions, you will discover a meaningful sentence.

1. The western hemisphere is never xenophobic first. (6)
2. Horse moves right, left, faster, by alternate routes. (5)
3. A most outstanding fate awaits the poor easterner later on. (5)
4. I do it, you are it, so it sounds like you should do it? (4)

**Solve the cryptic clues and find the final sentence.**

Hint:

> 3. What does 'outstanding' mean?
>  4. "I do it" = verb, "you are it" = noun, "sounds like" = homophone.

Comment: I earlier checked for all 4 letter words that can be used as both noun and verb, none made sense though. Working on "sounds like you should do it"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, *that* clue:

I do it, you are it, so it sounds like you should do it? (4)

> PREY: "prey" is both an intransitive verb ("I prey"), and a noun ("you are prey"), and is a homophone of "pray" (which is something you should do!).
>  (Also, as @randal'thor explains in the comments, this also fits semantically, since the **prey** of someone who is **prey**ing should **pray** that they escape!)

So, drawing from @Deusovi's answers to the other three clues, the final sentence is:

> **Sphinx trots after prey**

Comment: Yay, finally the 4th clue is solved! Note also how all three parts of the clue fit together semantically: if I am a predator, then I intend to **prey** (v) on you, my **prey** (n), so you should **pray** that you escape.

Comment: @randal'thor Ha, nice, didn't catch that! Added.

Comment: Nice!  I never did find this; glad you did

Answer (score 7):

#### Partial Answer (clues 1-3 solved)

The western hemisphere is never xenophobic first. (6)

> SPH(-ere) + I_ N_ X_ (no definition?)

Horse moves right, left, faster, by alternate routes. (5)

> _T _R + rOuTeS

A most outstanding fate awaits the poor easterner later on. (5)

> A F_E _R (with T inserted somehow?) → AFTER
>
>  or possibly...
>
>   A moved to the outstanding position of FATE → AFTE, then add _R

I do it, you are it, so it sounds like you should do it? (4)

Comment: Oooops, I forgot to put a definition part into the first clue. I wonder if anyone would mind if I edited the question to add a word or two somewhere ...

Comment: 1 and 2: perfect. 3: you've got the right answer but not the full explanation. 4: keep thinking :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I don't think anyone would mind, but it would be obvious that was the definition :P

Comment: An explanation for rot13 ( ibjf )  … this sound like a wedding, first person says ‘I do’ then it’s your turn and so should also do it (I do)?

Comment: @Tom: That doesn't make sense as a cryptic clue, though.

Comment: @Deusovi - I agree with you :) Sorry it was just a thought that came to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the complete answer to

3. A most outstanding fate awaits the poor easterner later on. (5)

> **A** + most outstanding **F**a**TE** + poo**R** easterner = **AFTER** = later on.

Comment: @deusovi already has that answer.  (And neither of you have used "awaits" yet, so there's probably something still missing)

Comment: But not a full explanation. I take 'awaits' to mean 'needs something added'.

Comment: That would be ... unusual.  :)

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation here?

Comment: @randal'thor I'm pretty sure they are saying `FTE` is "fate," mostly (75%) outstanding in the sense that "outstanding" can mean "remaining." At least, that was my guess after seeing Deusovi's answer, but before reading this one.

Comment: Actually I think @desuvi's second derivation makes more sense than mine.

Answer (score 1):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**:

The western hemisphere is never xenophobic first. (6)

> **SPHINX**  (Sph-Leftmost part of Sphere(Hemi-meaning we take one half), inx-First letters from "is never xenophobic". This contains no definition but two wordplay.

Horse moves right, left, faster, by alternate routes. (5)

> Not sure about this,it's probably **USHER**? (H and S from Horse, alternate letters of Routes-RUE. I am not sure about its definition being "Faster")

A most outstanding fate awaits the poor easterner later on. (5)

> No idea. Probably the last letters of something as indicated by "later on".

I do it, you are it, so it sounds like you should do it? (4)

> **URGE** - (Sounds like indicates homophones. You and are means U and R. "You should do it" part is probably the definition.

Comment: There's only one wordplay for the first clue, not two. And I don't quite see how you get the last one.

Comment: "You should do it" is like urging someone to do something...

Answer (score 1):

A simpler explanation for 3...

> 'A most outstanding' (anagram hint for.. ) 'fate' (anagram gives AFTE) 'awaits' (before) 'the poor easterner' (rightmost letter of poor - R) 'later on.' (definition - AFTER)

Alternatively...

> 'A most outstanding' applied to 'fate' means take the letter A from 'fate' and make stand it outside the word (put it first) - AFTE

.. *just realised this explanation was already suggested!*

Another suggestion...

> 'A' (A) 'most outstanding fate' (tall letters of 'fate' - FT) 'awaits' (before) 'the poor easterner' (rightmost letters of 'the' and 'poor' - ER) 'later on' (definition - AFTER). Although I would suggest 'easterners' would work better in the clue than 'easterner' if this is the case!

A wild stab in the dark at 4...

> RITE - 'I do it,' (write - You wrote the qu) 'you are it,' (right - I am, hopefully!) 'so it sounds like you should do it?' (rite - homophone, ritual one should perform or do according to tradition)

Which gives...

> SPHINX TROTS AFTER RITE. Which is feasible as an answer, if not wholly likely in this world!

Credit to @Deusovi for previously correct answers for 1-3

Comment: There is another Sphinx for PSE. But yeah, rite seems likely.

Comment: @Sid.. Yeah, right! ;)

Comment: Your third spoilertag is perfect for #3 - well done! But #4 still isn't r̶i̶t̶e̶ right: "sounds like" only appears once in the clue, so there's only one homophone involved.

Comment: @randal'thor Thanks for the feedback.. happy for #4 to be wrong, ('I do it' link felt very tenuous), but I think the one 'sounds like' with two homophones would probably be OK.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer

Note: uses parts from other answers, but has better explanations(IMO)

1. The western hemisphere is never xenophobic first. (6)

   > **SPHINX**
   >  Western(left) hemi(half) of **SPH**ere, **I**s **N**ever **X**enophobic first
   >  No definition
2. Horse moves right, left, faster, by alternate routes. (5)

   > **TROTS**
   >  right of 'lef**T**, faste**R**', by(next to) alternates of r**O**u**T**e**S**
   >  trots = horse moves
3. A most outstanding fate awaits the poor easterner later on. (5)

   > **AFTER**
   >  A + the most outstanding(non-doubled) letters in '**F**a**TE**' awaits the easterner(right-most) of poo**R**
   >  after = later on
4. I do it, you are it, so it sounds like you should do it? (4)

   > No, I didn't really solve it